# Selecting Random Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, random

I have three threads in my main class and if these are concurrently running how can I make the occurance of each thread in the iteration random? For example I have:

> Thread 1
>
> Thread 2
>
> Thread 3

and in the first iteration it may look like: Thread 2, Thread 1, Thread 3 and in second there could be different combination.

In addition, each of my threads has different outcome in this case an enumeration is assigned.
Also, every time these three threads are executed there are other three threads that compare the outcome of these and perform other executions based on that outcome. Then the process starts again.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "occurrence of each thread in the in the iteration random?"

Comment: What job are the threads doing?  Are they just printing out a line or are they consuming from a work queue or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way of notifying them, you could store them in an array or a list and pick a random number to decide which one you want.

Alternatively, you could have each thread `sleep()` for a random length of time. That should cause sufficient randomness, but may not be relied upon for production code, considering you're not guaranteed they will ever wake up. (It's 99.999999999% likely that they will, but that tiny fraction pops up way more than it should, and always when you cannot afford to.)

Note that this last one might end up with something like:

> Thread 1
>
> Thread 2
>
> Thread 1
>
> Thread 3
>
> Thread 2

Answer (score 0):

If your task is not inside a synchronized method or block then the tasks are happening at the same time. There is absolutely no way to control the order of completion for the tasks other than forcing a thread to wait until another thread has finished, which is very inefficient.

If your task is inside a synchronized method or block then there is no reason to multithread in the first place because synchronized blocks can only be executed by one thread at a time.